# Values are overridden and not added

Tags: java, oop

The values in the list are overriding in my program. I want to use the same object to add different values.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CommonValue {
    static int key = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = null;
        do {
            System.out.println("enter the how many element to add");
            int numOfElement = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            String userInput;
            int i = 0;
            do {
                // adding element in the list
                System.out.println("enter the element to add in the list");
                userInput = scan.next();
                list.add(userInput);
                i++;
            } while (i < numOfElement);
            // adding list in the map with key
            map.put(key, list);
            System.out.println(map);
            list.clear();
            // my intial key is 100 and it will incremented when i am going for another key
            key++;
            System.out.println("do you want to go for next key");
            System.out.println("y or n");
            choice = scan.next();

        } while (choice.equals("y"));
        for (Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            key = entry.getKey();
            ArrayList<String> value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println("key" + entry.getKey() + ": value " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> enter the how many element to add
>   2
>   enter the element to add in the list
>   a
>   enter the element to add in the list
>   x
>   {100=[a, x]}
>   do you want to go for next key
>   y or n
>   y
>   enter the how many element to add
>   1
>   enter the element to add in the list
>   z
>   {100=[z], 101=[z]}
>   do you want to go for next key
>   y or n

Actually the output I need is:

> {100=[a,x], 101=[z]}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you keep adding the same instance of `List` to the `Map` without making a copy. This will not work, because clearing the list outside the map also clears the list inside the map - after all, it's the same object.

Replace `list.clear();` with `list = new ArrayList<String>();` to fix this problem.

Comment: The real issue is you are not instantiating the arraylist collection inside the looping.... So the old instance of the collection is getting clear when you call clearlist()...
Also are you trying to reuse the same object again for memory optimisation??

Why do people upvote here?? The first answer itself is correct..

Comment: @Kannan_SJD *"Why do people upvote here??"* What? And are you sure you want to post that comment under this answer?

Answer (score 2):

You have to instantiate a new `List` for every Entry in your `HashMap`.
Currently, you are adding the very same List instance to every entry.
In combination with `list.clear()` this produces the observed output. The last entries in a (the only!) list will define the output for every key.

Answer (score 2):

Dear you are making mistake at belove line

```
list.clear();
```

instead of this just initialize list again with new instance as

```
list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: It is correct, that this is the problem, but can you explain _why_ it is the problem? Since OP doesn't know that, it would be helpful for him.